# How do you run a javascript code on multiple webpages with a chrome extension (if you're, for instance, automating Gmail sign in + mailing)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

My limited experience tells me that chrome extensions execute javascript code on the console of the website the code is run in. Thus, if we navigate away to a different webpage using the "this.document.location="www.somewebsite.com"" and expect the Javascript code to perform an action on the new page (say, button press), it wouldn't work because it would be looking for the button on the original webpage the code was run in.

Assuming I am correct, how do I work around this? I am building a google chrome extension to automate a task that requires navigation to multiple web pages.

(A question similar to mine here received answers that recommended using delay functions and none of those worked for me, and besides, I doubt that has anything to do with the problem here).

Comment: Extensions use the *background script* for that.

Comment: @wOxxOm I assume you mean the "chrome.tabs.executeScript({ //*javascript file to run*// })". I tried inserting the address to two javascript files there but it does not work. More specifically, I am unable to run them in the desired sequence.

Comment: The background script can 1) navigate the tab to a specific URL, 2) inject the content script via executeScript, 3) wait for the URL to change via chrome.tabs.onUpdated, 4) inject again. There are other solutions e.g. declaring content_scripts and using `chrome.storage`.